# How do I edit this matrix system of equations?

Tags: matrices

Is there a way to remove the right vertical line in the following matrix?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
   $    \begin{vmatrix} \alpha & -& \beta =180\\ \alpha & +&\beta =68
\end{vmatrix}$  
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
   $   \left| \begin{matrix} \alpha & -& \beta =180\\ \alpha & +&\beta =68
\end{matrix}\right.$  
\end{document}`?

Comment: Well that was scary fast. It works good.

Comment: Slow marmots get caught by the eagles. ;-)

Comment: @marmot it is better to run, dear marmot!! ^-^

Comment: I think a mod should strengthen the title of the question to improve the quality of it being searchable. I’m sure this is inherently duplicate to something else already on TeX SE, but perhaps it’s salvageable as a necessary duplicate that mirrors another way of asking the question.

Comment: @JoshDetwiler You are right. I edited it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You maybe want to use `systeme`, rather than a matrix for that, which makes for even easier input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\systeme[\alpha\beta]{
  \alpha-\beta=180,
  \alpha+\beta=68
}
\]
\[
\sysdelim|.
\systeme[\alpha\beta]{
  \alpha-\beta=180,
  \alpha+\beta=68
}
\]
\[
\syssubstitute{{a}{\alpha}{b}{\beta}}
\systeme[\alpha\beta]{
  3\alpha -  \beta = 180,
   \alpha + 2\beta = 68
}
\]

\end{document}
```

The traditional grouping is done with a brace, but you can also use a vertical bar as shown. If you want that all your systems have a vertical bar, type the `\sysdelim|.` command in the preamble.

[image]

Latin letters need not be declared as variables in the optional argument to `\systeme`.

Comment: Why not `cases` environment? Btw thank you for showing us the `systeme` package!!

Comment: @manooooh Because `\systeme` ensures good alignment.

Comment: @marmot Fixed..

Comment: Systeme looks awesome, but the documentation is in French!

Answer (score 5):

It does work with `matrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left| \begin{matrix}
\alpha & -& \beta =180\\ \alpha & +&\beta =68
\end{matrix} \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document} 
$ \left| \begin{array}{@{}*{4}{c@{\,}}l} 
\alpha & -& \beta &=&180\\ 
\alpha & +&\beta &=&68 
\end{array}\right.$ 
\end{document}
```

This is more effort, but avoids potential headaches like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160729/121799), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/388470/121799) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301053/121799).

[image]